# Absences report in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I've got a problem with finding a solution to my report. Purpose is to know how many times and how long employees spend time on breaks. This report is really imperfect to draw a data.
Purpose of my report:
- we need to know how long brakes they had.

The problem is that in this report I have some days and end date is below the start date - not beside. I copied by formula to have them beside to easily count the time but sometimes can happened that they have irregular leaves - eg. number 14 - he has only 5 records and I can't do it automatically because I need to know which record is missing. In my file is 10.000 records... 
Any prompts? Suggestions?

Thank you in advance for any tips!

Comment: Can you provide some sampledata in the post. I don't like downloading unknown Macroworkbooks.

Comment: It sounds like you first need to manually clean up your data sheet.  As they say: "Garbage In, Garbage Out".  Write some code with `COUNTA`, `COUNTBLANK` and/or `IF(A1>0,` or `IF(Len(A10>0,` to see if you can identify the "valid" or "invalid" rows.